# How to turn off Windows 10 touch screen gestures

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen, gestures

On my Lenovo Windows 10 touchscreen laptop on some programs (notably programs written in Processing), single taps have the graphical feedback of a circle appearing on the screen but a touch is not actually made on the program, to simulate a mouse click, I need to tap the touchscreen twice.

Also, when trying to hold down instead of holding down on the program, a box appears around my finger as if it is trying to register a right click. I turned off this in the settings but these programs still don't register touch screen taps unless I double tap the screen or drag.

Is there somewhere in Windows 10 I am able to disable these touch screen gestures and get the computer to instead treat touch screen single taps and holds the same way it would treat mouse clicks?

Comment: Does this article [Properly configure Windows PC touch and gesture behaviors](https://support.intuiface.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007434111-Properly-configure-Windows-PC-touch-and-gesture-behaviors) help?

Comment: @Seven I this used this to turn off holding to make a right click for the touch screen but my programs still don't register held taps on the touchscreen